# Postgres pull multiple future keys from sequence

Tags: mysql, postgresql, indexing, sequence

In Oracle I can do something like this to fetch a bunch of keys.

`select seq.nextval from dual connect by level <= 1000;`

I Postgres there is a nextval function, but how can multiple values be pulled at once?`

If someone also knows the answer for InnoDb I would be happy to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgresql, you can use something like this:

```
select nextval('mysequence') from generate_series(1,1000);
```

to get 1000 values from the sequence!  I don't think it's particularly safe to assume that these will be consecutive values, though.  You might need to wrap the `select` in a lock statement to ensure that competing results don't interleave.  If you don't care about consecutive values, then you don't need a lock.

Comment: I only need 1000 values that no other transaction will ever get. If they go 1,5,9,12,13,14,150 I don't care. Is that what you mean by "consecutive values"? p.s I'm running in read committed.

Comment: yes.  if you don't care about gaps, then this is exactly it.  I'm not sure your oracle example is any different, but the first thing that popped into my head was firebird's `generate(sequence, count)` which always returns consecutive values out of the sequence (actually it returns the last generated value, it's up to the caller to interpolate the intervening values.)

Comment: perfect, that's all I need. I don't know if the time for firebird has come already. Maybe in a few years time I will move to firebird. I'm happy porting the app to postgres first. p.s oracle is the same: it doesn't gurantee gap free sequences.

Comment: mnnneh... I can't think of any reason, in spite of native consecutive sequence reads, to favor firebird for anything.  PostgreSQL gets much more development attention, has hugely superior documenation, and has a heap of features firebird probably will never have.

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL has a suite of [functions that manipulate sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html). So you can do something like this. (But don't. See "use PostgreSQL's native cache" below.)

```
drop sequence test;
create sequence test;

-- You'll want to wrap these in a single transaction.
select nextval('test');                               -- Returns 1
select (setval('test', currval('test') + 1000)) as t; -- Returns 1001
select nextval('test');                               -- Returns 1002
```

There are a couple of other ways to get a bunch of values from a sequence. See docs for [CREATE SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html).

Have the sequence increment by 1000 instead of by 1. Let your application handle doling out the thousand values lower than nextval(). You will probably end up throwing away a lot of numbers.

```
drop sequence test;
create sequence test increment by 1000;
select nextval('test'); -- Returns 1; do this when you create the sequence.
select nextval('test'); -- Returns 1001
```

**Use PostgreSQL's native cache**.  I'm pretty sure this will be the most reliable and robust approach.

```
drop sequence test;
create sequence test cache 1000;
select nextval('test'); -- Returns 1.
select nextval('test'); -- Returns 2 from the cache; doesn't touch the sequence.
```

A different, concurrent session won't see the same thing.

```
select nextval('test'); -- Returns 1001
```

Comment: is the example with + 1000 telling me that between 1 and 1001 no other transaction got any key?

Comment: @FranzKafka: Yes, but I think using the native cache is a better idea. See my updated answer.